# Rails+Paperclip: How to spec a modified image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, rspec, md5

I let my users upload screenshots to the website. When saving, I do some modifications to the image, e.g. add a border to it.

I want to spec this behaviour. I tried it by comparing the MD5 hash of the uploaded modified image to an MD5 hash to a reference image. But this doesn't work: the MD5 hash of the uploaded image is always something different.

```
  describe 'print version of screenshot' do
    it 'adds a border to the screenshot' do
      pending "Doesn't work, MD5 of generated screenshot changes always."
      finding = create :finding, requirement: @requirement, project: @project, screenshot: File.open(dummy_file_path('screenshot.png'))

      generated_image_print_version = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.read(finding.screenshot.versions[:print].path))
      image_print_version           = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(File.read(dummy_file_path('print_screenshot.png')))

      expect(generated_image_print_version).to eq image_print_version
    end
  end
```

I'm not sure how MD5 works, but I guess it also takes file date or something similar into account. So this won't work.

Is there another way to compare image contents?

**Notice:** I add the border to the image for later export to Microsoft Word Docx using Pandoc, as there's no standard way to apply a border to every image in a document. For HTML output I would use CSS, for sure.

Comment: You could try http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/fileutils/rdoc/FileUtils.html#method-c-compare_file instead of generating hashes.

Comment: Probably not what you want to hear, but I'd add border & other effects with CSS, that's the right tool for the job IMO.

Comment: Thanks for this good note, Marko. I added some clarification to the question.